# Group radio button in listView

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, radio-button

How to use group button in listView ? In each row, it has two radio button.
The problem now is if I select one of the radio button , the radio button not showing it is selected.

```
      int value;
      Map<int, bool> answers = {};
      String _radioValue;
      String choice;
      int count = 0;
      
    ...item['questions']
                                      .asMap()
                                      .entries
                                      .map((items) {
                                    count++;
                                    return TableRow(children: [
                                      Padding(
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                          child: Text(items.value['name'])),
                                      Row(
                                        children: [
                                          Radio(
                                            value: items.value['id'],
                                            groupValue: count,
                                            onChanged: (val) {
                                              setSelectedRadioTile(val);
                                            },
                                          ),
                                          Text("Yes"),
                                          Radio(
                                            value: items.value['id'] + count,
                                            groupValue: count,
                                            onChanged: (val) {
                                              setSelectedRadioTile(val);
                                            },
                                          ),
                                          Text("N/A")
                                        ],
                                      )
                                    ]);
                                  }).toList()

 setSelectedRadioTile(int val) {
    print(val);
    setState(() {
      count = val;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay well I have built you a working version based on what you provided here. Please keep in mind that it would probably be a good idea to look at the documentation more in-depth so you get a feeling of how some widgets behave and what specific properties (like `groupValue`) are for. Also keep in mind that the following code is not optimised or whatsoever, I just got it worked out for your case - thinking about how to structure your data overall is some fundamental thing you should take a look at. Maybe try some out some flutter courses which are available or look at some youtube content from known flutter coders. But now back to some code stuff.

I used those properties in my `StatefulWidget` to work with. Since you use some kind of question map and I don't know how it looks like, I just used something bare bones:

```dart
/// Map which has the question ID as its key and the answer from the user (currently true for yes and false for no (or n/a as in your case)
Map<int, bool> _answers = {};

/// Map which holds the information of your questions. Right now only an ID to be able to reference it and the actual question - again very bare bones
Map<String, dynamic> _item = {
  'questions': [
     {
      'id': 0,
      'question': 'Is this legit?',
    },
    {
      'id': 1,
      'question': 'Oh really?',
    },
  ]
};
```

Then the method which will be called by the `Radio` widget once `onChanged` is triggered:

```dart
/// We need to know which question has been answered (therefore the ID) and which (bool) answer has been clicked by the user
_setSelectedRadioTile(int id, bool answer) {
  setState(() {
    _answers[id] = answer;
  });
}
```

And now the widget part - since your code starts where you iterate over the questions, I also share this part specifically:

```dart
/// Since the map itself is typed as <String, dynamic>, accessing 'questions' will return dynamic. Only we, as we know the structure, know that this is indeed a list. Therefore we need to cast this as "List<dynamic>" so we can iterate over it and won't get exceptions
(_item['questions'] as List<dynamic>)
.map(
  (question) => TableRow(children: [
    Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Text(question['question'])),
    Row(
      children: [
        Radio(
          /// The [value] property of Radio tells us, which property is used in [onChanged] - therefore now once this Radio is clicked, true is provided in the [onChanged] callback 
          value: true,
          /// [groupValue] is the value which this Radio is bound to. As you probably know, only one Radio button should be active for a group. So if you have a question which has several possible answers as radio buttons, we only want one of them to be active at a time. Thats what the [groupValue] is for. Since we iterate over all questions and every entity of a question (currently) has two possible answers (Yes and N/A), both those answers are for a specific question - the question with the current ID
          groupValue: _answers[question['id']],
          onChanged: (answer) {
            _setSelectedRadioTile(question['id'], answer);
          },
        ),
        Text("Yes"),
        Radio(
          value: false,
          groupValue: _answers[question['id']],
          onChanged: (answer) {
            _setSelectedRadioTile(question['id'], answer);
          },
        ),
        Text("N/A")
      ],
    )
  ]),
)
.toList(),
```

This should work on your side once you updated this example to fit with your data model. Again: I advise you to think about how you structure your data generally.

Comment: hi, would you mind to help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69689364/get-widget-value-in-listview-index